# Flag weight displaying a float value

Tags: support

I just noticed that the flag weight on my profile was displayed as a float. Is this normal?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your flag weight gets above 500 it doesn't rise in 10 point increments with ever flag that's marked "helpful".

There's a complicated formula, but basically as you get closer to 750 each flag is worth less and less. There are a lot of posts on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bflag+%2Bweight) about this - specifically [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82437/flag-weight-of-510-0000) which is identical to yours.

However, if a flag is "declined" then you lose 10 points regardless of your current flag weight.